# Using Select & Insert in the same query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I'm trying to do a SELECT from one and INSERT to the other with using ON on the three columns with the same values.

Here's what I trying...

```
INSERT INTO
CustomerDetails_TEST
(Region_ID)

SELECT
RegionStatesUS.Region_ID

LEFT JOIN Customers ON Customers.Customer_ID = CustomerDetails_TEST.Customer_ID
LEFT JOIN RegionStatesUS ON RegionStatesUS.RegionState = Customers.BillingStateOrProv

FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.Customer_ID = CustomerDetails_TEST.Customer_ID
```

The tables are...

```
CustomerDetails_TEST
RegionStatesUS
Customers
```

And I'm trying to `INSERT` the value from `RegionStatesUS.Region_ID` using the `Customer_ID` `INTO` `CustomerDetails_TEST`.`Region_ID`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN Customers ON Customers.Customer_ID = CustomerDetails_TEST.Customer_ID ' at line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is wrong, I think you might want this:

```
INSERT INTO CustomerDetails_TEST (Region_ID)
SELECT r.Region_ID
FROM Customers c1
LEFT JOIN CustomerDetails_TEST c2
    ON c1.Customer_ID = c2.Customer_ID
LEFT JOIN RegionStatesUS r
    ON c1.BillingStateOrProv = r.RegionState
```

Update query would be similar to this *not tested*:

```
UPDATE CustomerDetails_TEST c1
LEFT JOIN Customers c2
    ON c1.Customer_ID = c2.Customer_ID
LEFT JOIN RegionStatesUS r
    ON c2.BillingStateOrProv = r.RegionState 
SET c1.Region_ID = r.Region_ID
```

Comment: This is Great! What about the UPDATE, how would I use it for UPDATEing each record in `CustomerDetails_TEST`?

Comment: @Monty see my edit, your `UPDATE` would be similar to my edit.

Comment: Very simple! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

FROM comes before LEFT JOIN.  The error message is hinting at that.  Try again.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't see where to comment
just a note on how to update, or

```
insert into mytable
select from sometable
on duplicate key update
id = sometable.id;
```